# Get index by click from HTMLCollection

Tags: javascript, html

In HTML I have 9 `<div>`s with class ".square".

I want make them clickable, and I want to know how many times and which one is clicked and store it to array.

So if I clicked on fifth `<div>` 5 times its should be clicked[0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0]

```
    var button = document.getElementsByClassName("square");
    var clicked = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

    for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
       button[i].addEventListener("click", function () {});
       ;}
```

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlNgj.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the statement `let` for block-scoping on index/variable `i`.

```js
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("square");
var clicked = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

for (let i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  button[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    clicked[i] += 1;
    
    console.log(clicked);
  });
}
```

```html
<div class='square'>  [0] Click on me!</div><div class='square'>[1] Click on me!</div><div class='square'>[2] Click on me!</div><div class='square'>[3] Click on me!</div><div class='square'>[4] Click on me!</div><div class='square'>[5] Click on me!</div><div class='square'>[6] Click on me!</div><div class='square'>[7] Click on me!</div><div class='square'>[8] Click on me!</div>
```